# How to make the marker to spin around itself on place instead rotating in a circle?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio

This class code make the marker rotating in a circle around a point with a radius.  instead I want it to spin on place around it self.

I tried to make the marker to spin in place around its own axis but it keep rotating in a circle and spinning.

```
package com.example.test

import android.os.Handler
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker

class RotatingMarker(private val marker: Marker, private val handler: Handler) {
    private var isRotating = false
    private var rotation = 0.0

    fun startRotation() {
        if (!isRotating) {
            isRotating = true
            rotateMarker()
        }
    }

    fun stopRotation() {
        isRotating = false
    }

    private fun rotateMarker() {
        if (!isRotating) {
            return
        }

        // Rotate the marker by a small angle (e.g., 1 degree)
        rotation = (rotation + 1) % 360
        marker.rotation = rotation.toFloat()

        // Repeat the rotation with a delay (e.g., 10 milliseconds)
        handler.postDelayed({ rotateMarker() }, 10)
    }
}
```

and using in the activity kt code

```
val marker = mMap.addMarker(
                MarkerOptions()
                    .position(userLocation)
                    .icon(markerIcon)
                    .title("Marker Title")
            )

            rotatingMarker = RotatingMarker(marker!!, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))
```

Comment: Did you try with pivots ?